# Convert $\sin\theta/2$ using trig identities

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin\dfrac \theta2 = \sin^2θ+\cos^2θ-1$$

$$\sinθ = 2\sin^2θ+\cos^2θ-1$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Convert to what? The Dark Side?

Comment: It doesn't look like the right track. In your first equation, the right-hand side is $0$. A clearer description of what is asked for might be helpful. Perhaps the question asks you to express $\sin(\theta/2)$ in terms of trigonometric functions of $\theta$.

Comment: That was the question word to word.

Comment: Do you want to express $\sin {\frac{\theta}2}$ in terms of something else? - the question is confusing, and the assertions you have put do not help without an explanation of where they come from and what they are supposed to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event that you are being asked to solve for $\theta$ given the equation $$\sin\left(\frac \theta2\right) = \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta - 1,$$

...note that by the Pythagorean Theorem, we know that $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1.\;$

$$\begin{align}\sin\left(\frac \theta2\right) & = \underbrace{(\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta)}_{= 1} - 1 \\ \\ & = 1 - 1 \\ \\& = 0\end{align}$$
$$\implies \frac{\theta}{2} = \sin^{-1}(0) \implies \theta = 2 \sin^{-1}(0)$$

Comment: Clean and clear +1

Answer (score 3):

I can't begin to imagine how you got those identities... $\cos^2 + \sin^2 = 1$ so the RHS of the first is zero, for instance.

Here's a hint: start with the formula

$$\cos (2\psi) = \cos^2(\psi) - \sin^2(\psi).$$

1. Can you use any trig identities to write the right-hand side only in terms of sines of $\psi$?
2. Now set $\psi = \theta/2$. Can you rearrange terms to get a useful formula?